# Deploying local database to production and the other way around

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, deployment

I have a rails app that has a model called 'Opportunity'. Say this model has several records stored in the database on my local development environment and I now want to deploy the app. With it, I want all the data in my local database to be deployed as well.

Is this possible? I have looked at rake tasks and seeding but both do not seem to be quite what I want.

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: what sort of database dev and prod?

Answer (score 1):

For postgres the command to export your database is called pg_dump

To dump a database:

```
$ pg_dump mydb > db.out
```

To reload this database:

```
$ psql -d database -f db.out
```

Answer (score 0):

why cant you take table dump of development db and import it in production  db

For mysql

in development :
mysqldump -u username -p developmentdb tablename > for_production.sql

in production:

mysql -u username -p productiondb < for_production.sql